# Need to create an hyperlink in a calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calculated-column, json-formatting, 2019

We are using SharePoint 2019 On premises.

I have a column called "Email" that give the email address of the connected user, but in plain text.

I would like in another column to make this data as a link. So I created a calculated field. I tried several option found here and there, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I guess you want to use mailTo? SharePoint should render email-adresses in a list as link as default. Are they not links already even thought the list column is single line of text?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft officially does not support HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields and they have blocked the execution of HTML markup in calculated fields.

More details at: [Handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-fields-a3db28e4-747c-437e-b085-8f795b722a8c)

---

Now, solution for your requirement is based on if you are using classic experience or modern experience:

**1. Classic experience**:

If you are using classic experience, you can make the email address clickable using [Client Side Rendering (CSR)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

**2. Modern experience**:

If you are using modern experience, you can make the email address clickable using JSON formatting.

For example:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
    "elmType": "div",
    "children": [
        {
            "elmType": "span",
            "style": {
                "padding-right": "8px"
            },
            "txtContent": "@currentField"
        },
        {
            "elmType": "a",
            "style": {
                "text-decoration": "none"
            },
            "attributes": {
                "iconName": "Mail",
                "class": "sp-field-quickActions",
                "href": {
                    "operator": "+",
                    "operands": [
                        "mailto:",
                        "@currentField",
                        "?subject=Task status&body=Hey, how is your task coming along?.\r\n---\r\n",
                        "Click this link for more info. http://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ConferencePrep/Tasks/Prep/DispForm.aspx?ID=",
                        "[$ID]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Reference**: [Add an action button to a field (advanced)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#add-an-action-button-to-a-field-advanced)